# Vue3: error in ./node_modules/axios/lib/platform/index.js

Tags: frontend, vuejs3

I met a problem in vue3 configuration.

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                            15:39:50

 error  in ./node_modules/axios/lib/platform/index.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| export default {
|   ...utils,
|   ...platform
| }

 @ ./node_modules/axios/lib/defaults/index.js 8:0-44
 @ ./node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js
 @ ./node_modules/axios/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

can anyone help?
the dependency config. as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSZOJ.png)

nothing...............

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.1",
    "element-ui": "^2.15.14",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },

Answer (score 0):

problom solved. axios version is too high. use old one.

```
npm uninstall axios
npm install axios@0.25.0 --save
```

Comment: Older versions have security issues. Downgrading it is not a good idea.